# Why do we use “more ADJECTIVE” and “less ADJECTIVE” with adjectives of more than one syllable?

Tags: adjectives, comparatives, superlative-degree, inflectional-morphology, periphrastic-phrases

I've asked this question in Quora and the answers I got were:

> **First answer:**
>
> > Using "more" and "less" helps maintain clarity and consistency in comparative forms. It provides a straightforward and predictable way to form comparatives and superlatives without relying on
> > irregular or unpredictable suffixes.
>
> **Second answer:**
>
> > Longer adjectives often have complex or multisyllabic structures, making it more challenging to add suffixes like "-er" and "-est" without affecting the pronunciation or flow of the word. Using "more" and "most" allows for a smoother and more natural-sounding comparative form.
>
> **Third answer:**
>
> > Using "more" and "most" for more-than-one-syllable adjectives maintains consistency with two-syllable adjectives that also use "more" and "most" for comparison. This avoids creating separate rules or patterns for different types of adjectives

Is there an identifiable reason for tending to restrict the forms *-er, -est* to single-syllable adjectives? It may be one of these I suppose; or something else.

Comment: Those three answers seem completely made up, ChatGPT-generated, or both.

Comment: Related: [More bored *vs* boreder](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/474315/more-bored-vs-boreder)

Comment: It is one and two syllable adjectives. Anything with three gets more/most or less/least. Funny, funnier, funniest. Beautiful, more beautiful, the most beautiful. This question belongs on ELL.

Comment: Don’t limit yourself yourself to thinking about adjectives, because adverbs work the same way.  Here’s an example of comparative adverbs: *“Adjectives and adverbs form their respective comparative and superlative degrees in exactly the same way, so the **sooner** you notice this happening, the **better** you’ll understand it.”* :) Please don’t take that sentence harshly; it’s just a demo.

Comment: @tchrist Wow, the way you speak to people. Really too much.

Comment: @Lambie Did you miss what I did there, even with the smiley? I was trying, by way of demonstration, to use comparative-degree adverbs in my text; you know, like *sooner*.

Comment: the most unkindest cut.  (if it was good enough for Shakespeare ...)

Comment: I assume it's to avoid turning long words into even longer words but not sure how to prove that.